# Read a multielement list, look for an element and print it out in python

Tags: python, latex, split, multiline, lines

I am writing a python script in order to write a tex file. But I had to use some information from another file. Such file has names of menus in each line that I need to use. I use split to have a list for each line of my "menu". 
For example, I had to write a section with the each second element of my lists but after running, I got anything, what could I do?

This is roughly what I am doing:

```
    texfile = open(outputtex.tex', 'w')
    infile = open(txtfile.txt, 'r')
        for line in infile.readlines():
            linesplit = line.split('^')
            for i in range(1,len(infile.readlines())):
               texfile.write('\section{}\n'.format(linesplit[1])) 
               texfile.write('\\begin{figure*}[h!]\n')
               texfile.write('\centering\n')
               texfile.write('\includegraphics[scale=0.95]{pg_000%i.pdf}\n' %i)
               texfile.write('\end{figure*}\n')
               texfile.write('\\newpage\n')
    texfile.write('\end{document}')
    texfile.close()
```

By the way, in the inclugraphics line, I had to increace the number after pg_ from "0001" to "25050". Any clues??

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: An example of the input file and the output you would expect would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite follow your question. But I see several errors in your code. Most importantly:

```
    for line in infile.readlines():
    ...
    ...
        for i in range(1,len(infile.readlines())):
```

Once you read a file, it's gone. (You can get it back, but in this case there's no point.) That means that the second call to `readlines` is yielding nothing, so `len(infile.readlines()) == 0`. Assuming what you've written here really is what you want to do (i.e. write `file_len * (file_len - 1) + 1` lines?) then perhaps you should save the file to a list. Also, you didn't put quotes around your filenames, and your indentation is strange. Try this:

```
with open('txtfile.txt', 'r') as infile:    # (with automatically closes infile)
    in_lines = infile.readlines()
in_len = len(in_lines)

texfile = open('outputtex.tex', 'w')
for line in in_lines:
    linesplit = line.split('^')
    for i in range(1, in_len):
        texfile.write('\section{}\n'.format(linesplit[1])) 
        texfile.write('\\begin{figure*}[h!]\n')
        texfile.write('\centering\n')
        texfile.write('\includegraphics[scale=0.95]{pg_000%i.pdf}\n' %i)
        texfile.write('\end{figure*}\n')
        texfile.write('\\newpage\n')
texfile.write('\end{document}')
texfile.close()
```

---

Perhaps you don't actually want nested loops?

```
infile = open('txtfile.txt', 'r')
texfile = open('outputtex.tex', 'w')
for line_number, line in enumerate(infile):
    linesplit = line.split('^')
    texfile.write('\section{{{0}}}\n'.format(linesplit[1])) 
    texfile.write('\\begin{figure*}[h!]\n')
    texfile.write('\centering\n')
    texfile.write('\includegraphics[scale=0.95]{pg_000%i.pdf}\n' % line_number)
    texfile.write('\end{figure*}\n')
    texfile.write('\\newpage\n')
texfile.write('\end{document}')
texfile.close()
infile.close()
```

Comment: I should add that if you just want to iterate over the lines in a file in a simple way, you don't need `readlines()` -- just do `for line in infile:`. `readlines()` creates an intermediate list, which is unnecessary unless you want to save it.

Comment: Hi @senderle, that is exactly what I need!!!. I don't really want to save the list, just read some information and put it in text. REALLY THANK YOU. By the way, when I write the \section line, what I need in the text file is something like: \section{blablabla} but as "{}" is used for the format thing, I don't know how to write it right.

Comment: @Alejandro, ah, sorry I didn't test that. You need to put an index number in the braces. As in `'section{0}'.format(5)`. At least if I understand you correctly.

Comment: ok this is what I want in the section line: I had a text file with each line as menu^submenu^subsubmenu^pagNum. I want to write this figure part for each submenu that I had. Everything seems to be perfect, but I realise right now that with this code I had several times the same submenu. Any idea?

Comment: Hmmm. I don't quite follow yet. Try this -- show me (1) the way you want the string to look after formatting and (2) the thing you want to pass to `format()`. So something like this: 1. `'the_string_you_want_to_be_written'`. 2. `['the', 'list', 'you', 'want', 'to', 'pass', 'to', 'format']`.

Comment: (1) '\section{America}' (2) ['Capitals of the World', 'America', 'Buenos Aires', '34']

Comment: OH! Ok, now I understand. Easy: to insert a literal `{`, just insert two, like this: `{{`. So to insert a field inside, you need a total of three: `'\section{{{0}}}\n'.format(linesplit[1])`.

Comment: Close.. but not quite yet :). In my text file (where my classification "menu" is) has like a 25000 lines. Now I have a 25000 parts of \section{America} and then 25000 \section{Europa} and so on.. what could it be?

Comment: Ok, so this is what I meant by writing `file_len * (file_len - 1) + 1` lines -- you had two nested loops, so if your file was 25000 lines long, then it was writing 25000 lines in your output file _for all 25000 lines_. In other words, 25000 * 25000 lines! See the bottom of my answer for a version without nested loops.

Comment: @senderle just a last question: if I want to add a line like section but for chapter (I mean, print: \chapter{Capitals of the World}) how could I print it just once?? (i.e. because there is a lot of lists that starts with Chapitals of the world). My first try was to create a list called chapter where I wrote all the chapters and then added just below the linesplit= line.split.., this: for i,u in enumerate(chapters[1:]): if linesplit[0] == chapters[i]: texfile.write('\chapter{{{0}}}\n\\newpage\n'.format(linesplit[0]))